# Should I use service caching or activemq caching as part of Web 8 and DD4T 2.1 implementation?

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion, cache-channel-service, dd4t-2

If my understanding is correct. with service caching the object is cached on service(rest) layer and not on presentation layer, but if we use ActiveMQ(DD4T) it provide the feature to cache the object on presentation layer it self.

I am wondering which one would be best and what you guys suggest or do we need to use both?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using DD4T caching with ActiveMQ cache invalidation, that allows you to keep DD4T objects cached for a long period (until they get invalidated).

However, your application may still be (indirectly) using the CIL API as well. So, I would recommend to also enable CIL caching (but with a relatively short Time To Live, e.g. 1 minute).

BTW: for Java CIL, you should set TTL very low (e.g. 5 seconds) on an XPM-enabled site, to avoid caching latency issues with XPM sesstion preview (CIL.NET is smart enough to detect session preview requests and bypass caching for those).

Comment: I am using apachemq to invalidate tridion object cache and it is working fine. but it is not working with dd4t. The dd4t cache is not getting refreshed even after the tridion object cache invalidation. I have included nuget package DD4T.Caching.ApacheMQ and have provided config value but not sure if I am hooking it up properly or not.